Validate assignee is part of area path team in Azure DevOps
When assigning a work item in Azure DevOps, I want to validate that the "Assigned to" area is set to a member of the team corresponding to the Area Path or prohibit users from assigning a work item to someone who is not in the corresponding Area Path assigned teams.
For instance, if I have two groups, Group A and Group B, and each has their respective Area Paths (e.g., "Project\GroupA" and "Project\GroupB"), I want to set a rule so that only Group A members can be assigned to tasks within "Project\GroupA" and not in "Project\GroupB", and vice versa for Group B members.
I don't want to prohibit either groups from viewing and editing the work item otherwise from the other groups, just the "Assigned to" value.
Is there a simple way to do this?
I have tried to set up rules for the work item types in the Project Settings > Boards > Process > 'Work item type' > Rules, and add new rule, but I am not able to find a condition or action that match my requirements.
I also tried looking into Project Settings > Boards > Team Configuration > Security. Here I have found the option to "Edit work items in this node" and deny this for the teams that I don't want to give this permission to (or deny this by default in the root project and then allow for the specific teams I do want to have this permission), but I don't really want to do this as this feels too restrictive, and I am only interested in validating that the "Assigned to" field is correctly set.
Update:
I have submitted a feature request for this in the developer community of Microsoft. I am sharing the link here if anyone would like to vote for it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Validate-that-assignee-of-work-item-is-p/10698443

Currently, there isn't such rule/feature in Azure DevOps to restrict the value of the "Assigned To" field to users in a specific group.
You can submit a feature request on Developer Community. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. You can share the link of the suggestion ticket here so that others who wants the same feature can follow and vote for it.
